# Python stops working on Windows and console freezes

Tags: python, windows, windows-console

Firstly, I'm a pen tester, so I use Python & Perl all the time. I programmed a Python script for mass test exploiting of Wordpress to test all websites on a server. The script works perfectly on Linux (Kali Linux & Ubuntu ), but when I use it on Windows, it works for only 5 or 10 minutes, and then the console stops working completely. I can't exit the script normally. I can only exit Python if I close the console window. I don't think the problem is in the script because other scripts show the same problem. If I change windows, it's still the same problem.

Here are some lines of my Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests, re, urllib2, os, sys, codecs                   
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool                          
from time import time as timer  
import time 
from random import sample as rand                       
from platform import system 
from colorama import Fore                               
from colorama import Style                              
from pprint import pprint                               
from colorama import init                                               
init(autoreset=True)
try:
    with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], mode='r', encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as f:
        ooo = f.read().splitlines()
except IOError:
    pass
ooo = list((ooo))



def banners():


    if system() == 'Linux':
        os.system('clear')
    if system() == 'Windows':
        os.system('cls')

        banner = """{}{} \n \n

    Coded to w

        \n""".format(fc, sb)
print banner
Agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0'}
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3"
baaReflexlibr = requests.get(url)

        if "/wp-content/" in baaReflexlibr.text:
            print ''.format(fg, fg, url, fc,fc, sb,fr)
            wpsbot(url)         
        else:
            print ''.format(sb, sd, url, fc,fc, sb,fr)
except:
        pass
def wpsbot(url):



    try:
        some exploits and 0days
  except:
        pass




banners()


def Main():
    try:

        start = timer()
        ThreadPool = Pool(30)
        Threads = ThreadPool.map(sitebul, ooo)
        print('Time: ' + str(timer() - start) + ' seconds')
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Comment: This is waay to much code.  Please cut this down to a minimal, complete, verifiable example so someone can more easily help you.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with your try-except blocks, and print the exceptions

Comment: chrisz, thank you but the problem isn't code i think. t.m.adam  thank you sorry i'm a beginner here.

Comment: My guess is that it's network related (`requests` or `urllib2`). Try setting a timeout.